# Миграция отдельных Post types (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Появилась потребность перенести только определенные Post Type`ы с сайта на сайт клон.

О чем я? Например есть следующие типы постов: яблоки, груши, абрикосы. Нужно перенести только посты типа "груши".

Пробовал искать разные плагины. Из того что могло бы подойти - только WP Migrate DB PRO. Там есть функция исключения определенных типов постов. Но работает она криво. Так как удаляет все типы постов кроме нужного.

Какие есть идеи?)

Comment: https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/ работает как надо

Comment: @Krya не могу найти нужные настройки. Можно скрин? Или укажи раздел где искать. Спасибо

Comment: А стандартный экспорт чем не угодил?